# Convert CSS Selectors to XPath selector in python without external libraries

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, xpath

Is it possible to convert complex CSS Selectors such as:

```
@[class="maintitle"] > .main-wrap #myid > .h1 bold
```

To XPath in Python 3 **without using external libraries**? Or with regex?

I'm currently able to convert

```
@[class="maintitle"]
```

to `"//*[contains(@class,'maintitle')]"` but cannot manage to create a global rule to convert these more complex selectors. Is it even possbile?

Edit: I can't use cssselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath

```
//*[@class="maintitle"]/*[contains(@class, "main-wrap")]//*[@id="myid"]/*[contains(@class="h1")]//bold
```

If you need tool that can convert CSS to XPath for you, you can try [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html):

```
from cssselect import GenericTranslator
from lxml.etree import XPath

css_selector = """[class="maintitle"] > .main-wrap #myid > .h1 bold"""
print(XPath(GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath(css_selector)))
```

*Output* (looks weird, but...):

```
descendant-or-self::*[@class = 'maintitle']/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' main-wrap ')]/descendant-or-self::*/*[@id = 'myid']/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' h1 ')]/descendant-or-self::*/bold
```

Note that you might also need to add `//` at the beggining as:

```
print("//" + str(XPath(GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath(css_selector))))
```

Comment: I need a global code in python 3 to convert the given css selector to an xpath. The selector above was just an example.

Comment: Andersson's better than any global code you could hope for.  :-)

Comment: I know but I need a global code, not a specific one because my xpath vary

Comment: Is it possible to do it without cssselect? I'm can't  to use it. I can use lxml.etree

Comment: `cssselect` should be installed separately from `lxml`. Try `pip install cssselect`. P.S. You cannot get required result without `cssselect`... I mean you cannot implement current solution without it.

Comment: There is another possible solution without using cssselect? Can't use it.

Comment: I managed to use cssselect, I created a function where I pass the selector and give me back the converted xpath. But I have the following error: error -> TypeError
 xpath_literal() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: and how `xpath_literal()` looks like?

Comment: xpath_literal() is a function from the modules I imported

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be using lxml:

You can pass "//" as a param to **XPath(GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath(css_selector)**

something like this
**XPath(GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath(css_selector,"//")** to avoid **descendant-or-self::** at the beginning

Comment: This mostly looks like a rehash of the existing accepted answer from nearly four years ago. Please don't repeat answers. See [answer].